# How can a user with SSH keys authentication have sudo powers in Ansible?

Tags: ansible

I create a vm in the azure cloud with the following ansible script:

```
---

- name: azure playbook
  hosts: localhost
  vars_files: ['vars.yaml']
  tasks:
  - name: Create VM with defaults
    azure_rm_virtualmachine:
      resource_group: "{{account_prefix}}_rg"
      vm_size: Standard_D1
      name: "{{account_prefix}}-vm1"
      storage_account_name: "{{account_prefix}}store1"
      network_interface_names: "{{account_prefix}}vm1eth0"
      ssh_password_enabled: false
      admin_username: owen
      ssh_public_keys:
      - {  path: /home/owen/.ssh/authorized_keys,
        key_data: ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQDH0q4pmdkJcc/JPVJui5uWMV12GsJAsDCosfUSSFZfTIx92bb9FC3hx1zU7tD1+Zw3aQW13m6ZS2T ... YnvieSbdD3v}
      image:
        offer: CentOS
        publisher: OpenLogic
        sku: '7.2'
        version: latest
```

but when running a further script to add another user:

```
---

- name: create user
  hosts: my-vm1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com
#  vars_files: ['vars.yaml']
  remote_user: owen
  tasks:
  - name: Create User
    user:
      name: andrea
      password: $6$rounds=656000$1AspdTb0lfOSc5yM$bAkPgHkuHwap/j6f0P88WxOdjxq3MCRO7/qgufYB.s/4t4k99wwtu/.../
      group: users
      shell: /bin/bash
    become: true
```

I get "sudo: a password is required" error:

```
PLAY [create user] *************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
fatal: [my-vm1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "failed": true, "module_stderr": "", "module_stdout": "sudo: a password is required\r\n", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "parsed": false}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
        to retry, use: --limit @8-add-admin-user-to-vm-with-userpswd-already.retry
```

My inventory looks like this:

```
my-vm1.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com ansible_ssh_private_key_file=/home/myuser/.ssh/id_rsa ansible_user=owen ansible_become=true
```

So how can the user have sudo privileges and so use ansible 'become' and the like?

Note that the same result happens when ansible_user and ansible_become are omitted from the inventory file.

EDIT: If I ssh on to the vm as owen (from the box with the ssh private key, that created the vm) then I am able to run sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers and access that file. So does owen have sudo privileges or not? I'm getting confused now!! Am I misunderstanding the error from the ansible add user script?

EDIT2: I think this question is invalid - as the user does have sudo privileges added manually through the portal. I'm still not sure what's going on but I don't think this question is coherent - or really represents the actual problem I'm trying to solve.

Answer (score 10):

You can either change the sudo config for the user owen with this command:

```
sudo visudo -f /etc/sudoers
```

and change the line with user owen to this:

```
owen ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL
```

then sudo won't require Ansible to enter the password. Or you could instruct Ansible to ask you for the password with the parameter `--ask-become-pass` like this:

```
ansible-playbook site.yml --ask-become-pass
```